# Use intersection theory to show that a closed 4-manifold is not homotopy equivalent to $S^2\times S^2$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $R_\theta: S^2\to S^2$ be the counterclockwise rotation around $z-$axis. Define $M$ to be the closed 4-manifold obtained by gluing two copies $A_1,A_2$ of $B^2\times S^2$ along their common boundary $S^1\times S^2$. The gluing map is $(e^{i\theta},v)\to(e^{i\theta},R_{\theta}(v))$. The problem asks to 
i) compute the homology of $M$;
ii) find another closed 4-manifold $N$ which has the same homology and show that it is not homotopy equivalent to $M$ by using intersection theory.
For part i), I have found that $M$ has the same homology as $S^2\times S^2$. I'm stuck with part ii).
**My Questions:**

- I have noticed that $M$ is the nontrivial bundle $S^2\tilde{\times}S^2$ so it remains to compare the intersection forms of $S^2\times S^2$ and $S^2\tilde{\times}S^2$. Using cup product I managed to show that the former can be represented by a matrix \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix} but how to compute that of the nontrivial one?
- Since I didn't know how to compute the intersection form, I tried to find some other approach to avoid that. Suppose $I_2$ is the intersection form mod 2 of $S^2\times S^2$. Because the matrix of $I_2$ is known, $I_2(\alpha,\alpha)=0$ for any homology class $\alpha$. In particular, the self intersection number mod 2 of any 2 dimensional submanifold is 0. Therefore, it would be done if there exists some 2 dimensional submanifold of $M$ whose self intersection number mod 2 is 1. Is there any simple way to construct such a submanifold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to view $S^2\subseteq \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}$, imagining that the rotation occurs in the $\mathbb{C}$ portion (so $\{0\}\times\mathbb{R}$ is the $z$-axis.)

For $i=1$ and $i=2$, let $N_i\subseteq A_i$ be defined as $N_i = B\times \{(0,1)\}$.

Suppose $p = (e^{i\theta}, (0,1))\in \partial N_i$, the boundary of $N_i$.  Then the gluing map (which I'll call $f$) is $f(e^{i\theta},(0,1)) = (e^{i\theta}, (0,1))$, so we can view $f$ as a homeomorphism $\partial N_1\rightarrow \partial N_2$.

In particular, we can glue $N_1$ to $N_2$ to obtain a closed manifold $N$.

**Proposition**  The manifold $N$ has self intersection number $\pm 1$.

To prove this, we'll first construct a deformation of $N$.  To that end, for fixed small real number $t\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, consider the subset $N_1(t) = B\times \{(\sin(t),\cos(t)\}$.

Note that $N_1(0) = N_1$, so this is a deformation of $N_1$.  At the boundary $\partial N_1(t)$, the gluing map $f$ takes the form $f(e^{i\theta}, (\sin(t),\cos(t)) = (e^{i\theta}, (e^{i\theta} \sin(t),\cos(t)))$.

Now, consider $N_2(t) = \{(re^{i\theta}, (re^{i \theta}\sin(t), \sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2(t))} \}$.

Note that $N_2(0) = N_2$, and that $\partial N_2(t)$ (which occurs when $r=1$) is given by $\partial N_2(t) = \{(e^{i\theta}, e^{i\theta} \sin(t), \cos(t))$}.  That is, $f:\partial N_1(t)\rightarrow \partial N_2(t)$, so for each $t$ we can glue to obtain a smoothly embedded submanifold $N(t)$.

Having defined $N$ and $N(t)$, we can now compute the intersection $N\cap N(t)$.

**Proposition**:  For $t\neq 0$, $N\cap N(t) = \{ 0,(0,1)\}$.

**Proof**:  In $N$, every point has last coordinate $(0,1)$.  So we need to determine when this happens for $N(t)$ with $t\neq 0$.

In $N_1(t)$, the last coordinate is $(\sin(t),\cos(t))$, so $N_1(t)$ is disjoint from $N$ for all $t\neq 0$.  In $N_2(t)$, since $t\neq 0$, we find that the last coordinate is $(0,1)$ iff $r = 0$.

When $r=0$, we obtain the point $(0,0,1)\in N_2\cap N_2(t)$.  $\square$

Now that we've computed the intersection, we need only show that $N$ and $N(t)$ intersect transversely at $(0,0,1)$.

**Proposition**  The intersection at $(0,0,1)$ of $N$ and $N(t)$ is transverse.

**Proof**: Observe that $T_{(0,(0,1))} B\times S^2$ can be identified by $T_0 B\oplus T_{(0,1)}S^2\cong \mathbb{R}^2\oplus \mathbb{C}$.

Then $T_{(0,(0,1))} N = \mathbb{R}^2\oplus 0$, obviously.

Now, consider the curve $\alpha(s) = (s, s\sin(t), \sqrt{1-s^2 \sin^2(t)})$.  This curve lies in $N(t)$ (take $t=s, \theta = 0$).  Then $\alpha'(0)$, when projected to $\mathbb{C}$, is $\sin(t)$, which is a non-zero real number for $t\neq 0$.

Lastly, consider the curve $\beta(s) = (ise, is\sin(t), \sqrt{1-s^2 \sin^2(t)})$.  This curve lies in $N(t)$ (take $t=s, \theta = \pi/4$).  Then $\beta'(0)$, when projected to $\mathbb{C}$, is $i\sin(t)$, which is a non-zero purely imaginary number for $t\neq 0$.

Thus, we see the intersection is transverse. $\square$

Now that we have a unique point of intersection, and the intersection is transverse, it follows that $N$ has self intersection number $\pm 1$, as claimed.

Comment: This answer is probably messier than it needs to be, since I've never actually computed an intersection number by bare hands before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a very nice construction, though it does look more complex than I expected. So you think it will be easiest to compute the intersection form of M instead? If that's the case, as mentioned in my first question, how to do that?

Comment: Do you, for example, know that the non-trivial $S^2$-bundle over $S^2$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}P^2 \# -\mathbb{C}P^2$?  The cohomology ring of this space can be computed in terms of that of $\mathbb{C}P^2$, and then you can read off the intersection form via Poincare duality.  If you don't know something like that, then the only way I know how to compute the intersection form is computations as in my answer.

Comment: That said, my answer is definitely the hard part of the computation of the intersection form of $M$.   If you consider $P:=\{1\}\times S^2$ in $A_1$, then $P$ intersects $N$ in the unique point $(1,(0,1))$, and the intersection is transverse.  So, $P$ also defined a homology class, and it's easy to see that $P$ has self intersection number $0$ since $P$ can be deformed to $\{e^{i\theta}\}\times S^2$ for some fixed $\theta$.  I claim that $H_2(M)$ is generated by $P$ and $N$ so that one can now fully compute the intersection form, modulo signs.  To see this, we argue as follows...

Comment: First note that $P$ is not a multiple of $N$ (in $H_2$):  if $P = kN$, then $0 =P\cdot P = kN\cdot kN = k^2 (N\cdot N) = \pm k^2,$ so $k = 0$.  But $P\cdot N\neq 0$, so $P\neq 0\in H_2$.  If follows that for any $X\in H_2(N)$, some multiple of $X$ is a combination of $P$ and $N$:  $a X = bN + cP$ for some $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{Z}^3$.  Intersecting both sides with $P$, we get $a(X\cdot P) = \pm b$, which implies $a|b$.  Instead intersecting both sides with $N$, we get $a(X\cdot N) = \pm b \pm c$.  Since we already know $a|b$, it now follows that $a|c$.  Thus, we can divide by $a$ to find that...

Comment: $X = \frac{b}{a}N + \frac{c}{a}P$.  We have now shown that $\{N,P\}$ is a basis of $H_2(M)$.  The intersection form is therefore $\begin{bmatrix} \pm 1 & \pm 1\\ \pm 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, for some choice of signs.

Comment: (It's too late for me to edit, but in my definition of $P$, I should have used $\{0\}\times S^2$, not $\{1\}\times S^2$)

Comment: I fully understand your second approach but I’m curious about your first proof. Where can I find a proof of the fact that M is diffeomorphic to that connected sum? Sorry for so many questions. I have literally zero knowledge about sphere bundle.

Comment: I don't know where to find a proof that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}P^2\# -\mathbb{C}P^2$, but I'll just write one here.  View $\mathbb{C}P^2$ as follows.  Start with $S^2$ and consider the Hopf bundle $S^1\rightarrow S^3\rightarrow S^2$.  By extending the fibers to disks, we obtain a disk bundle $D^2\rightarrow E\rightarrow S^2$ which has boundary $S^3$.  Gluing a $4$-ball to $E$ along the boundary $S^3$, we obtain a manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}P^2$.  But this makes it explicit that if we remove a ball from $\mathbb{C}P^2$, what's left ($E$) has the structure of....

Comment: a $D^2$-bundle over $S^2$.  Now, take two copies of $E$.  They both have boundary $S^3$, so they can be glued together via the identity map to make a smooth manifold $E\cup E$.  Note that if we glue by the identity, this preserves the fiber $S^1$s on the boundary $S^3$, so gluing by the identity allows the bundle projections $\pi:E\rightarrow S^2$ to glue together to a bundle projection $\pi:(E\cup E)\rightarrow S^2$.  The fiber is $D^2\cup D^2$ glued via the identity, that is, the fiber is $S^2$, so we've created an $S^2$-bundle over $S^2$.  Now, because $E$ is $\mathbb{C}P^2$ with a ball...

Comment: removed, it follows that $E\cup E$ is either $\mathbb{C}P^2 \#\mathbb{C}P^2$ or $\mathbb{C}P^2 \# -\mathbb{C}P^2$.  But when forming the connect sum of oriented manifolds, the gluing map is taking to be orientation reversing.  Our gluing is the identity, so in order to be orientation reversing, we must be using $E$ and $-E$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it.